# How can I fix error H31 at Heroku/PointDNS?

Tags: heroku, pointdns

I use PointDNS to manage my DNS. In July, they had a [migration](https://support.pointhq.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500008650301-Important-DNS-and-Nameserver-Changes-) from IPv4 to IPv6, but I did everything they recommended for the migration.

Heroku also had an [update](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/rust-lang/infra-team/41/875859108), but I checked everything mentioned on this email (I didn't get the email myself), and everything seems to be the way it's supposed to be. Any idea on what might be the issue?

I have no idea if I configured something wrong if Heroku is having issues ([this doesn't seem related](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2311)), or if PointDNS is having issues ([says the last downtime was 4 hours ago](https://status.pointhq.com/))

```
2021-08-13T21:48:45.365853+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H31 desc="Misdirected Request" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=site.com.br request_id=2bcf003e-1c07-4fd7-a549-5a7488699c8d fwd="179.24.194.180" dyno= connect= service= status=421 bytes= protocol=https agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Looks to me like PointDNS/heroku's fault. I have a ticket open with them, but not response yet. Everything looks configured properly on my end. Guessing they messed up the DNS just like they messed up whatever their other update was.

Comment: My h31 errors started as soon as the H10 errors stopped, and I'd never run into H31's before. This seems related: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2151

Comment: Switching to DNSSimple seems to have helped - still propegating and still getting some H31s, but much less than before.

Comment: @maxhud I'll try that. Too bad their `How to diagnose H31 errors` article is actually quite weak.

Comment: Weak is right!!

Comment: @maxhud they replied to my ticket saying the error was related to the H10 errors. Kinda pissed they make a big migration on Friday, then only come back to look at it on Monday, but well, what you're gonna do (other than migrate to AWS maybe)

Answer (score 0):

It may sound kind of weird but, my app was working in some instances while not working on others.

I simply just renamed the application, thinking that changing the DNS *might* help with the problem and to my surprise, it did!

I'm trying to get into the root cause of this, and would update the answer once I have something concrete. Till the time being, try renaming your application and it may help.

P.S. I know this question is old, but still posting an answer in case anyone else is looking for a way out.